# SVG viewBox Coordinates

Tags: svg, viewbox

I'm just learning details about the SVG viewport and viewBox.  What I find confusing is, that it seem counter-intuitively, despite all positive x and y coordinates going left to right and top to bottom respectively in web design, the viewBox coordinate system seems to go right to left, and bottom to top respectively?

Am I understanding this correctly, and does anybody know why this is the case.

Thanks

Comment: the viewBox is just an area, it really doesn't go from bottom to top.

Comment: Hi robert, yes i know that I'm talking about where it is positioned within the SVG viewport (or SVG root element).

Answer (score 1):

This is not correct. viewBox declaration is x, y, width, height. And the origin 0,0 is top left - like most coordinate systems. If you have an example that is different, then it may be that there is a transform being applied at some level of your doc or CSS that is changing behavior.

Comment: Hi Michael, here is a link, there's no transform on the SVG or in the CSS. If you change the x and y values of the viewBox from `0 0 100 300` to `15 0 100 300` the graphic moves to the left, not the right. 
https://codepen.io/emilychews/pen/qKGwwK

Comment: This is a long explanation. This is a good summary: http://www.sarasoueidan.com/blog/svg-coordinate-systems/

Comment: Also - play around with this to get the feel of how different viewBox and preserveAspectRatio settings affect positioning https://codepen.io/mullany/pen/WyqGrm

Comment: @TheChewy Conceptualize the viewBox as defining a transparent window in an opaque layer above the SVG canvas. When altering the viewBox attribute, you move the 'window' to the right without affecting the canvas - so  your graphics move left relative to the 'window'. The browser anchors the viewBox window, so it appears that the coordinate change would affect the graphics.

Comment: The penny has dropped now. Because you move the viewBox to the right and down it creates the illusion that the graphic is moving to the left and up.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The penny has dropped now. Because you move the viewBox to the right and down it creates the illusion that the graphic is moving to the left and up.