# svg viewbox question/bug implemented in svg.js

Tags: svg, viewbox, svg.js

I'm writing a svg graphic to the screen using html and a library svg.js. When I apply a viewbox, I get a strange behavior that I do not understand and cannot resolve. The code difference between the working and non-working code is as follows:

Working code:

```
//Works great
svg = SVG(document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0]);
draw = svg  //.viewbox(0, 0, 300, 300)
```

Broke:

```
//XY coordinates are off weird amounts
svag = SVG(document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0]);
draw = svg.viewbox(0, 0, 300, 300) //adding view box causes the problem
```

Implementation:

```
function drawRect(e) {
    var rectX = e.clientX;
    var rectY = e.clientY;
    draw.rect(10,10).move(rectX, rectY).fill("#00FF00")
```

broken/working:

forgive my clumsiness here.. the green squares are off, and more off the further you get away from point (0,0).  By "off" I mean that the green squares do not appear where the click happened. By some factor.

[image: showing how off clicks from position of green rect are]

I'd like to know how to adjust my code for the viewbox:

possibly related: [SVG viewBox Coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51194690/svg-viewbox-coordinates)

Comment: the e object has other properties, however all of them show the same coordinates.

Comment: Adding a viewBox applies a transform, because the contents are now being scaled to fit the viewport (the size of the SVG on the page).  They are no long 1:1.  So that means the location of, say, (100,100) in SVG coordinates, is probably no longer at (100,100) on the page.  You will now have to convert your mouse coordinates to SVG coordinates.  To do that in svg.js use the [point()](https://svgjs.com/docs/2.7/manipulating/#geometry) function. As Fuzzyma says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jugging the point through SVG via where (SVG.handlerMap[0] === `<svg` dom node  object) seems to do the trick

```
var p = SVG.handlerMap[0].createSVGPoint();
p.x = rectX;
p.y = rectY;
var pN = p.matrixTransform(SVG.handlerMap[0].getScreenCTM().inverse());
rectX = pN.x;
rectY = pN.y;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to transform the mouse coordinates into the coordinate system of the svg. You can do that by using the `point()` method:

```
p = draw.point(e.clientX, e.clientY)
draw.rect(10,10).center(p.x, p.y).fill("#00FF00")
```